# Loading FeynCalc

Tags: packages, feyncalc

I am trying to install the FeynCalc package, but I cannot load it, it always gives the following errors:

> Loading FeynCalc from /home/gabi/.Mathematica/Applications
>   SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to fcdevel. >>
>   SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to fcloops. >>
>   General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to .gvfs. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of SetDirectory::cdir will be suppressed
>   during this calculation. >>
>
> ResetDirectory::dtop: Directory stack is empty. >>

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Do not install from a read-only USB stick, but do it from a directory where you have write permissions.

Comment: See https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the problem, there is a bug with feyncalc 8 and linux 12
http://www.feyncalc.org/forum/0768.html